# Firebase get Data From Multilevel Random Id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Firebase database  setup:

[image: Firebase database]

This successfully puts my workflow name to intent i.

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Workflow, WorkflowHolder>(
            Workflow.class,
            R.layout.list_row,
            WorkflowHolder.class,
            ref) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(WorkflowHolder holder, Workflow workflow, final int position) {
            holder.setName(workflow.getName());
            holder.setNextdue(workflow.getNextdue());
            holder.setLastcompleted(workflow.getLastcompleted());
            final String workflow_name = workflow.getName();

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Begin Workflow");
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you are ready to begin workflow " + workflow_name + "?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {




                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CompleteWorkflow.class);
                            i.putExtra("workflow_id", adapter.getRef(position).toString());
                            i.putExtra("workflow_name", workflow_name);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //TODO
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    workflows.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    workflows.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, I would like all the tasks of the workflow, so basically be able to put a json of all the tasks to intent i. Is there any way in which this possible?

Also, my Workflow.class is as such:

```
public class Workflow {
private String name, lastcompleted;
private Long nextdue;

public Workflow(){
}

public Workflow(String name, Long nextdue, String lastcompleted) {
    this.name = name;
    this.nextdue = nextdue;
    this.lastcompleted = lastcompleted;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getNextdue() {
    return nextdue;
}

public void setNextdue(Long nextdue) {
    this.nextdue = nextdue;
}

public String getLastcompleted() {
    return lastcompleted;
}

public void setLastcompleted(String lastcompleted) {
    this.lastcompleted = lastcompleted;
}
```

}

Any thoughts on how to restructure that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can just encapsulate all of the information about a `workflow class` into a `workflow object`, which implements `Parcelable interface`.

The code will look similar to yours, but instead of passing 2 different extras you can just pass a single one, which is the workflow object. Assuming that you have in your POJO class as setters `setWorkFlowId` and `setWorkFlowName`, please use the following code:

```
Workflow workflow = new Workflow();
workflow.setWorkFlowId(adapter.getRef(position).toString());
workflow.setWorkFlowName(workflow_name);
i.putExtra("workflow, workflow);
```

For more information on implementing a `Parcelable`, please see [Parcelable Offical Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

You can also use `Serializable` instead of Parcelable, but it is significantly slower. So IMHO is the easiest option.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get "Cannot resolve symbol movie". Where did movie come from?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be `workflow`, which is the object of `Workflow class`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: This is helpful, but not exactly what I need. What I really need is to know how to pull the tasks, not how to parse the data that already works. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: In this case, in the `CompleteWorkflow` activity create another listener and get the data from the `Tasks` node again and don't transfer it from an activity to another.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of developer communication does it again, tasks turned out to be an ArrayList. Thanks for your help though, everyone!